# Chartit is not a valid tag library:Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My **views.py** file is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from chartit import DataPool, Chart
from chartit.chartdata import DataPool
from weather.models import MonthlyWeatherByCity
import simplejson
from chartit import DataPool, Chart

def weather_chart_view(request):
    ds=DataPool(series=[{'options': {'source': MonthlyWeatherByCity.objects.all()},'terms': ['month','houston_temp','boston_temp']}])    
    cht = Chart(datasource = ds, series_options =[{'options':{'type': 'line','stacking': False},'terms':{'month': ['boston_temp','houston_temp']}}],chart_options ={'title': {'text': 'Weather Data of Boston and Houston'},'xAxis': {'title': {'text': 'Month number'}}})
    return render_to_response('chart.html',{'weatherchart': cht})
```

The **urls.py** file inside the app is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from weather import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.weather_chart_view , name='weather_chart_view')
]
```

The **models.py** file is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class MonthlyWeatherByCity(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField()
    boston_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    houston_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
```

The **chart.html** file is as follows:

```
<head>
    <!-- code to include the highcharts and jQuery libraries goes here -->
    <!-- load_charts filter takes a comma-separated list of id's where -->
    <!-- the charts need to be rendered to                             -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{ weatherchart|load_charts:"container" }}
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'> {{ weatherchart|load_charts:"container" }}</div>
</body>
```

On running the server and opening the app I am getting the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /weather/
'chartit' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading chartit.templatetags.chartit: cannot import name simplejson
```

I have also included the app, chartit and json in the **INSTALLED_APPS**.

As you can see I have also imported simplejson in views. Where am I going wrong?

Please suggest if I need to post anything else to make the problem lucid.

Comment: Have you tried {% load charts %} ? In the docs of chartit, How to use, point 4, it says: 
Use the {% load_charts %} template tag to load the charts to HTML tags with specific ids. And are you sure you really have the 'simplejson' app in your installed apps list?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what is needed to be done? Ans if you are talking about the HTML file, my file has that already.

Comment: Do this: Instead of using {% load chartit %} in the template file you have up there, use {% load charts %}. Its complaining of two things there, I don't know how interrelated they are, but its likely the 'simplejson' app isn't installed. Or if installed, perhaps it needs the 'python manage.py syncdb' command to refresh the db.

Comment: @Rexford tried syncdb. No change. Also tried `load charts` instead of `load chartit`. No change.

Comment: By the way, You've imported "simplejson" in the views.py without using it. Why?

Comment: Highchart requires it.

Comment: You don't need to include `simplejson` or `json` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` - these are python modules, not django applications. Make sure you have `simplejson` installed in your python environment: `pip install simplejson`.

Answer (score 13):

There is a fix for the problem on the github page of the project. Do a `pip install simplejson` and then locate the file `chartit/templatetags/chartit.py` in the chartit module and replace the line of simplejson import as shown below.

```
from django import template
-from django.utils import simplejson
+import simplejson
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```

It looks like a hack but works till the fix is merged.

Answer (score 7):

1. You need to add `chartit` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in "settings.py"

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'chartit',
   )
   ```
2. Then, follow @akoshodi 's response.

Answer (score 2):

In latest version of **chartit** **(0.2.8)** issue is fixed, so *the only* thing that you should do is to add 'chartit' in **INSTALLED_APPS** exactly as @MiaeKim mentions.